# Getting invalid length parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error

> Invalid Length Parameter passed to LEFT or SUBSTRING function

when running this code. It has something to do with the sku when I am join because if I comment out the criteria on joining the skus, the code will work fine.

Can anyone assist? Thanks!

Code:

```
WITH [did] AS
( 
    SELECT
        [did].[InvoiceNumber] AS Invoice,
        [did].[CustomerLotReference] AS Container,
        [did].[WarehouseSku] AS warehouessku,
        [did].[Description] AS description,
        SUM([did].[invoice]) AS invoiceqty,
        CAST([did].[CreateDate] AS DATE) AS createdate
    FROM 
        [server].[123].[table] AS did
    WHERE 
        [did].[table] = 'ABC'
        AND [did].[CreateDate] > GETDATE() - 30
    GROUP BY 
        [did].[InvoiceNumber],
        [did].[CustomerLotReference],
        [did].[WarehouseSku],
        [did].[Description],
        CAST([did].[CreateDate] AS date)
), [so] AS 
(
    SELECT
        [so].[OrderGroup] AS container,
        REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber])) - 1)) AS sku,
        SUM([so].[QtyShipped]) AS AllocatedQty
    FROM
        [server].[123].[table] AS so
    WHERE 
        [so].Status <> 0
    GROUP BY
        [so].CustomerOrderNumber, [so].[OrderGroup], [so].OtherReferenceFour
)
SELECT
    [did].*, [so].*
FROM
    [did]
LEFT JOIN
    [so] ON did.Container = so.container
         AND did.warehouessku = so.sku
```

Comment: Hi - that doesn’t appear to be a valid SQL statement, I’m guessing you’ve missed the first line which is probably something like “with [did] as …”. The fact that you are using the same names for you CTEs as you are for table aliases makes your code difficult to read. Without knowing your data it’s difficult for anyone to help you but I’d suggest running the CHARINDEX function in isolation and you’ll probably find some invalid numbers such as zero

Comment: Thanks for the call out, I updated the code.

I've tried to run the CHARINDEX function and works fine, until I add the "and did.warehouessku = so.sku" segment. If I comment this out, then the code will work

Comment: So the CHARINDEX function didn’t produce any zero/null values? What happens if you run the REVERSE statement I.e. SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE([so].  [CustomerOrderNumber]))-1)) from [server].[123].[table] as so

Comment: If I run the function with only LEFT JOIN
    [so] ON did.Container = so.container it will run perfectly. I tried isolating without the join and looks like the gave me an error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likelihood is that your use of `charindex` is returning zero because it did not find a space in the `[CustomerOrderNumber]`then you have 0 -1 and that -1 is invalid in the `left` function. To avoid this there is a hack to avoid the problem by concatenating the character you are searching for to the column value so that the `charindex` can never return zero and you avoid the negative number once you subtract the 1.

```
    , REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]),
        CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]) + ' ') - 1)) AS sku

                                               see above ^^^^^^^^
```

So now, even if `[CustomerOrderNumber]` has no space in it, charindex will find a space and then return a positive length (equal to length of the column value).

see this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TGb9i3oz)

Comment: Ok this seemed to help. By chance do you know why ```charindex``` return zero if ```CustomerOrderNumber``` consistently has a space ?

Comment: Yes. If it cannot find the thing you asked it to look for, it returns zero. From the documentation: "*If CHARINDEX does not find expressionToFind within expressionToSearch, CHARINDEX returns 0.*" see [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Ok Thanks Adrian. If there were ```-1``` or ```-2``` values at the end of the integer, is there a way to remove this while incorporating your function?

Comment: if the wanted string isn't found by charindex you get zero. immediately after you subtract 1, so the result is -1 (it cannot be -2). If the source string already has a space in it, then adding an additional space will not affect the charindex result.. If the source string does not have a space in it, adding the extra space will allow charindex to return the length of the source string + 1 and immediately after you -1 and so the final result is that you have the length of the source string without the extra space.

Comment: SO, you get valid responses by charindex and you avoid the error. You do not need to remove the extra space because it is removed by the left function. There's nothing more I can add here. Please work through the nested function calls manually on paper - that should help.