# How do I remove the last values by delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to remove the delimiter along with the value(s) in the `sku` column. Any help would be appreciated!

**TABLE**

| container | sku | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YMLU1234567 | 534164 | 1877 |
| YMLU1234567 | 987876 | 554 |
| YMLU1234567 | 987876-1 | 91 |
| YMLU1234567 | 987877 | 841 |
| YMLU1234567 | 987877-1 | 106 |

**Current code**

```
SELECT
    [so].[OrderGroup] as container,
    REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]),
    CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]) + ' ') - 1)) AS sku,
    sum([so].[QtyShipped]) as AllocatedQty
FROM [server].[dbo].[table] as so
WHERE [so].Status <> 0
AND [so].CustomerName ='alpha'
AND [so].[OrderGroup] ='YMLU1234567'
GROUP BY  [so].[OrderGroup], REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]),
          CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE([so].[CustomerOrderNumber]) + ' ') - 1))
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Sorry! I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: I see you have adopted the [added space answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77478163/2067753)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

All the work is done in the `CROSS APPLY`. It outputs a clean *sku*.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (container VARCHAR(20),sku VARCHAR(10), qty INT);
INSERT @tbl (container, sku, qty) VALUES
('YMLU1234567', '534164',   1877),
('YMLU1234567', '987876',   554 ),
('YMLU1234567', '987876-1', 91  ),
('YMLU1234567', '987877',   841 ),
('YMLU1234567', '987877-1', 106 )
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-';

SELECT container, t1.sku, SUM(qty) AS AllocatedQty
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT(sku, CHARINDEX(@separator, sku + @separator) - 1)) AS t1(sku)
GROUP BY container, t1.sku;
```

**Output**

| container | sku | AllocatedQty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YMLU1234567 | 534164 | 1877 |
| YMLU1234567 | 987876 | 645 |
| YMLU1234567 | 987877 | 947 |

Comment: Will this work if I have to do this for an entire table and not just one container? thanks!

Comment: Correct. It will work for all containers in the table.